# A sufficiently general tag wiki for "trace"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

This question has two parts:

1. Can someone propose a *sufficiently general* tag wiki for [trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trace)? Click through to the tag to see what questions are currently tagged there (in particular, I am not sure how to include the one about Connes/Weil's trace formulae or the one about Galois theory). I am imagining the [trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trace) to contain the linear algebraic trace and its direct generalisations; I hope that is reasonable.
2. Trace has some other meanings in mathematics; at least three others appear in Wikipedia: [field trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace), [trace operator in analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator) (which is like a restriction operator, but for restrictions of certain measurable functions to certain measure zero sets...), and [trace monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_monoid). Which of these should be included in the [trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trace) and which should be split off?

Comment: Is this not an example of tags being *too* specialised? Does the tag "trace" help you make a decision on whether to click on a question or not? Does it help catalogue a question or not? Perhaps the cataloguing would be useful for the linear algebra usage, but I would suspect a "no" answer would probably prevail for the others...

Comment: The field trace, at least, is a linear algebra trace, so those are fine together. The others I haven't met so I don't know their etymology.

Comment: A recent related post: [Should the PDE notion of trace be tagged with the 'trace' tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31688). At the moment, tags with "trace" in the name are also ([tag:trace-map]) and ([tag:field-trace]).