# Should the PDE notion of trace be tagged with the 'trace' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is the [trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trace) tag supposed to be used for questions about the trace operator from Sobolev theory (analysis)?

I was going to de-tag "trace" from a question, but it seems like it's not the first time this happened,

- [Trace Theorem: a question about Evans' proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605364/trace-theorem-a-question-about-evans-proof)
- [A question about a detail in the proof of trace zero theorem Evans](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567064/a-question-about-a-detail-in-the-proof-of-trace-zero-theorem-evans)
- [Trace theorems and Sobolev Spaces in unbounded domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553855/trace-theorems-and-sobolev-spaces-in-unbounded-domains)

The description of the trace tag says it can be about the "trace of functions", but its quite far off from the other meanings of "trace" in mathematics, but I suppose it would help someone search, e.g.  if they search for a combination of tags "trace" with "pde". Should I let it be?

This question has been almost asked before here, but with no answer: [A sufficiently general tag wiki for "trace"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/a-sufficiently-general-tag-wiki-for-trace)

Comment: Here is a SEDE query looking for instances where (trace) was removed: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1038474/questions-which-no-longer-have-the-given-tag-including-the-editor?tagName=trace - I have mentioned a few [similar queries in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2020/5/11). I will also mention that there is a tag called ([tag:trace-map]) which has empty tag-info. It is used [11 times with (sobolev-spaces)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trace-map+sobolev-spaces).

Comment: 11/34 is a much larger proportion than 48/1148 (trace+sobolev-spaces vs just trace tag). I suppose you're suggesting that one option to consider would be to repurpose trace-map?

Comment: Another unrelated use of the word, knot traces, is a [hot topic recently](https://www.quantamagazine.org/graduate-student-solves-decades-old-conway-knot-problem-20200519/).  I'm in favor of using distinct tags for such widely separated topics, and will supply tag information for [tag:trace-map].